# In-Memory Binder for Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream

Is there a lightweight 'in-memory' binder for Spring Cloud Stream that would allow me, for example, to wire together and deploy a set of microservices in the same address space (i.e. a single Java process)?

Answer (score 2):

There is not an in-memory binder but, when using the (preferred) functional programming model (not the deprecated annotation-based model), you can compose multiple functions together.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_functional_composition

> Functional Composition
> Using functional programming model you can also benefit from functional composition where you can dynamically compose complex handlers from a set of simple functions. As an example let’s add the following function bean to the application defined above

```java
@Bean
public Function<String, String> wrapInQuotes() {
    return s -> "\"" + s + "\"";
}
```

> and modify the `spring.cloud.function.definition` property to reflect your intention to compose a new function from both ‘toUpperCase’ and ‘wrapInQuotes’. To do so Spring Cloud Function relies on | (pipe) symbol. So, to finish our example our property will now look like this:

> `--spring.cloud.function.definition=toUpperCase|wrapInQuotes`

Answer (score 2):

Let me clarify a little
There is an in-memory binder that was specifically build for testing - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_testing. We use it all the time.
However, i want to stress that it was not build for any production usage. For that we simply have [Spring Integration project](https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration) that allows you to wire complex flow. Spring Cloud Stream is actually build on top of Spring Integration, but build specifically for *distributed microservices*. So any attempt to subvert that would be an anti-pattern.

Comment: I can easily imagine a scenario where you deploy the same set of services differently in different environments. E.g. in the same process for free-tier clients and distributed and independently scalable for premium clients, or something along those lines. Having the same code with independent services but flexible configuration of the communication channels (in-memory vs a message queue) between services sounds very cool and perfectly reasonable (not anti-patterny), no?